# Why does defining a value make the script break when the value is not even used

Tags: interface

The script works perfect

```
class ObjectShading(bpy.types.Panel):
bl_label = "Shading"
bl_idname = "ObjectShading"
bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
bl_category = "Claas"

def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    obj = context.object
    mesh = obj.data

    row = layout.row()
    row.label(text="AutoEdgeBreak:")
    row = layout.row()
    row.prop(mesh, "use_auto_smooth", text="BreakEdge")
    row.active = mesh.use_auto_smooth and not mesh.has_custom_normals
    row.prop(mesh, "auto_smooth_angle", text="Angle")
    row = layout.row()
    row.label(text="ManualSmooth:")
    row = layout.row()
    row.operator("object.shade_smooth", text="Smooth", icon="SMOOTHCURVE")
    row.operator("object.shade_flat", text="Sharp", icon="LINCURVE")
    row = layout.row()
    row.prop(obj, "draw_type", text="Draw Type")
    row = layout.row()
    row.prop(obj, "show_wire", text="Wire")
    row.prop(obj, "show_transparent", text="Transparency")
    row.prop(obj, "show_x_ray", text="X-Ray")
    row = layout.row()
    #row.prop(mat, "alpha")
    split = layout.split()
```

But when I add the following value definition no buttons are drawn

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    obj = context.object
    mesh = obj.data
    mat = context.material
    cmat = mat.cycles
```

What I try to do is to add an alpha value slider so I can set transparency for display and value in one area.

```
row.prop(mat, "alpha")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, errors in the script's draw function will stop it from drawing beyond the line where the error happens (or it will stop drawing your panel entirely). The error you got is:

```
location: <unknown location>:-1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/ui_panel.py", line ---, in draw
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'material'
```

Fix this error and the panel will draw OK. It means `context.material` is the problem.

Get in the habit of starting Blender from Terminal during experimentation / development process. This will allow you to read the errors that occur when Blender doesn't explicitly tell you something's wrong.

Comment: Ok now I understand why I don't always see errors. Have to google how to start it from terminal under win10.

Comment: Using windows you can open a terminal window from Window -> Toggle System Console. See [blender.org/manual/.../console_window.html](https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/window_system/console_window.html) --- but Blender on Linux and OSX don't have that feature.

Comment: OS X you open terminal and then drag blender into the window and hit enter.

Comment: sure. but windows is the only platform with the `Window -> Toggle System Console` in Blender. (just to be clear)